# Formatting a Text in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

I have a text of the form

```
1;#aa2;#dde4;#sdfsa6;#hjjs
```

I want to remove `digit` and `;#` from the above string and keep the string as

```
aa
dde
sdfsa
hjjs
```

Is there a way like we do in C# to check if string contains `<digit>;#` and replace it with a 
 or a blank space.

I was trying to split on `;#` as

```
=(Split(Fields!ows_Room.Value,";#")).GetValue(1)
```

but than the output is only `aa2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try to following expression.

```
    =Join(Split((System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Fields!ows_Room.Value, "[0-9]", "").Trim(";").Trim("#")),";#"),” “)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting aa2 only because GetValue(1) retruns the first indexed array value.
Change you expression to

```
    = Join(Split(Fields!ows_Room.Value,";#"),” “)
```

If you want the output like

```
aa2
dde4
sdfsa6
hjjs
```

use this expression

```
    = Join(Split(Fields!ows_Room.Value,";#"),VBCRLF)
```

Comment: The output is `1aa 2dde4 sdfsa 6hjjs` i also dont want any digit